# Why id Chrome extension popup closing on input autocomplete suggestion click?

Tags: angularjs, forms, google-chrome-extension, safari

For a Chrome extension, I am using the popup as a login form with Angular.

But on **OS X**, when I click on the username autocomplete suggestion, the popup close itself like when you click outside of the popup. But it works well on Windows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->

  <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-if="loggedIn">
    <p>
      <img src="images/logo-full.png">
    </p>
    <p class=""><strong>You're logged in as:</strong>
    </p>
    <p><i>{{user}}</i>
    </p>
    <br>
    <div class="center-block">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>
      <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-href="https://example.com/cockpit" target="_blank">Go to Cockpit</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="!loggedIn">
    <p>
      <img src="images/logo-full.png">
    </p>
    <form ng-submit="login(username, password)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="username" required placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="password" required placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-if="error">{{error}}</div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="loading">Log in</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <a href="https://example.com/auth/reset" target="_blank"><small>Forgot your password?</small></a>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="margin-top-big">
      <a href="https://example.com/auth/signup" target="_blank" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><strong>Don't have an account? Get started</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <script src="lib/myLib.js"></script>

  <!-- build:js scripts/popup.js -->
  <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Hey, did you find solution for this problem?

Comment: @JsIsAwesome Still not. I'll let you know if it the case

Answer (score 3):

It seems that OSX handles the click on the text popup as the click outside of the extension popover area, which causes it to close.

I've observed it on extensions for Safari and Chrome, but only on OSX.
Here's a [related ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587481) in the Chromium bugtracker.

In some cases you can make a custom control which will use divs to display popup content, preventing this issue. For the autofill, I don't think the workaround exists. You can try to disable autofill completely in OSX browsers. Hardly a better solution, but might be appropriate for you.

Comment: :-( has any work around been found in the last year, also encountering the same problem.